# Use thymeleaf template of another project

Tags: maven, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

There seems to be problem if using thymeleaf for multiple projects.

Let's say I have a spring application in project 2 & the controller in project 1. With proper @ComponentScan defined, the application able to display the view/html in my template folder. But once I added the thymeleaf-layout-dialect maven dependency, it failed with "There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404)." error.

My projects:

[image: structure]

The prj1 pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>macrohard.org</groupId>
  <artifactId>prj1</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> 
    </parent>

 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
</project>
```

The prj2 pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>macrohard.org</groupId>
  <artifactId>prj2</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>macrohard.org</groupId>
        <artifactId>prj1</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

The hello-world.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>HW</title>
</head>
<body>
    Hello World!!
</body>
</html>
```

The App2 in prj2:

```
package prj2;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "prj1"} )
public class App2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App2.class, args);
    }
}
```

The Controller1 in prj1

```
package prj1.web;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/api")
public class Controller1 {

    // this can be run by App2 & App1
    @GetMapping(value="/hello")
    public String hello() {
        return "hello world";
    }

    // this can be run by App1 only
    @GetMapping(value="/hello2")
    public ModelAndView hello2() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.setViewName("hello-world");
        return mav;
    }

}
```

As in Controller1, The "api/hello" can be requested successfully because it doesn't involve the template. But for the "api/hello2" request, it unable to render the hello-world.html. Here are the error stacks:

```
2019-07-02 22:21:28.758  INFO 19680 --- [           main] prj2.App2                                : Started App2 in 1.89 seconds (JVM running for 2.454)
2019-07-02 22:21:51.807  INFO 19680 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-07-02 22:21:51.807  INFO 19680 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-07-02 22:21:51.807 TRACE 19680 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver@2ded92
2019-07-02 22:21:51.810 TRACE 19680 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : No LocaleResolver 'localeResolver': using default [AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver]
2019-07-02 22:21:51.811 TRACE 19680 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : No ThemeResolver 'themeResolver': using default [FixedThemeResolver]
2019-07-02 22:21:51.814 TRACE 19680 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : No RequestToViewNameTranslator 'viewNameTranslator': using default [DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator]
2019-07-02 22:21:51.817 TRACE 19680 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : No FlashMapManager 'flashMapManager': using default [SessionFlashMapManager]
2019-07-02 22:21:51.817 DEBUG 19680 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : enableLoggingRequestDetails='false': request parameters and headers will be masked to prevent unsafe logging of potentially sensitive data
2019-07-02 22:21:51.817  INFO 19680 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 10 ms
2019-07-02 22:21:51.829 TRACE 19680 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/api/hello2", parameters={}, headers={masked} in DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-07-02 22:21:51.834 TRACE 19680 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView prj1.web.Controller1.hello2()
2019-07-02 22:21:51.843 TRACE 19680 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.m.a.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod : Arguments: []
2019-07-02 22:21:51.851 DEBUG 19680 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/webp, image/apng, application/signed-exchange;v=b3, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8]
2019-07-02 22:21:51.851 TRACE 19680 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView: name 'hello-world'; URL [hello-world]] 
2019-07-02 22:21:51.851 DEBUG 19680 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : View name 'hello-world', model {}
2019-07-02 22:21:51.853 DEBUG 19680 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : Forwarding to [hello-world]
2019-07-02 22:21:51.857 TRACE 19680 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "FORWARD" dispatch for GET "/api/hello-world", parameters={}, headers={masked} in DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-07-02 22:21:51.860 TRACE 19680 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to HandlerExecutionChain with [ResourceHttpRequestHandler ["classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/", "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/", "/"]] and 3 interceptors
2019-07-02 22:21:51.862 DEBUG 19680 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Resource not found
2019-07-02 22:21:51.862 TRACE 19680 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : No view rendering, null ModelAndView returned.
2019-07-02 22:21:51.862 DEBUG 19680 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "FORWARD" dispatch, status 404, headers={}
2019-07-02 22:21:51.864 DEBUG 19680 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND, headers={}
2019-07-02 22:21:51.865 TRACE 19680 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/error", parameters={}, headers={masked} in DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-07-02 22:21:51.865 TRACE 19680 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : 2 matching mappings: [{ /error, produces [text/html]}, { /error}]
2019-07-02 22:21:51.866 TRACE 19680 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2019-07-02 22:21:51.875 TRACE 19680 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.m.a.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod : Arguments: [org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@6fdc83, org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade@119a78b]
2019-07-02 22:21:51.885 DEBUG 19680 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, text/html;q=0.8]
2019-07-02 22:21:51.886 TRACE 19680 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Rendering view [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$StaticView@216e30] 
2019-07-02 22:21:51.908 DEBUG 19680 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 404, headers={}
```

I am certain that it is due to thymeleaf-layout-dialect, because if I remove it from pom.xml everything work fine. 
The problem is I need it to layout thymeleaf page. How to display the template in another different project from spring application?

Comment: Uh - why not just copy the template into the second project?

Comment: @paulsm4
It is not that I want to share the template between projects /controllers. In real world scenario, prj1 & prj2 will have their own different templates. Only those templates related to prj1 will be in prj1, and same for prj2. There will be also Controller in each project. Now, I only have one Spring App, which I should put it in prj2 since prj2 has dependency on prj1. Then the problem as above will occur when the App try to use Controller1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have published an example project, I can't follow the issue :/

Are you sure you did not just confuse the "hello world" messages from the controller with the message from the template?

When I modify: `\prj1\src\main\resources\templates\hello-world.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>HW</title>
</head>
<body>
    Hello World!! (from Template in prj1)!
</body>
</html>
```

I had to add this into pom.xml of prj1 because of some weird classpath issue:
(the thymeleaf-layout-dialect lib you use seems to bring in an additional thymeleaf jar - did not investigate that)

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
     <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
     <version>3.0.11.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>
```

When I run prj2 app and call: `http://localhost:8080/api/hello3` or `http://localhost:8080/api/hello2`
I get:

```
Hello World!! (from Template in prj1)!
```

Which is what we want?

When I call: `http://localhost:8080/api/hello`
I get an error because of some not found template ("hello world" is of course not a template file).

So I'm not sure why it does not work for you :/

Comment: Thanks a lot @wemu

Cause: When added the thymeleaf-layout-dialect to maven dependencies, maven will use old version thymeleaf-3.0.00.RELEASE.jar which doesn't work well.

Solution: Need to add the thymeleaf dependency as you did, then maven will use the thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar without problem. 

Should I blame maven or thymeleaf?

Comment: well non of them. maven is a dependency management tool, it does some automatic things to match the most common outcome but only as an assumption. the dependency management itself still remains a developer responsibility. So which version ends up in your project is your job to tell maven. Maven uses a 'shortest path' algorithm to determine which version of an artifact to use. In this case I assume the wrong version was closer that the correct one. So one could also exclude the thymeleaf dependency from the layout dependency to fall back to the spring provided version. So the developer chooses.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how this works without that dependency. The controllers that work with templates can return the template name directly. And you are implementing rest controllers which suggest different defaults than required for working with templates (like the content types).

So a controller that would invoke a template looks like (this is my way of doing it, can't claim I know its the only one):

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@Controller
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    public MyController() {
    }

    @RequestMapping("/hello-world")
    public String hello(Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("someKey", "someValue");
        return "hello-world"; // this is the template name in src/main/resources
    }

}
```

And this way it is also possible to have controllers / templates bundled in one jar and use them in a different spring boot application as dependencies. Since it is all classpath based ([there is a property to configure this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html): spring.thymeleaf.prefix) this just worked for me.

I think the reason really is your rest controller - which might confuse things a bit.

Comment: I had tried your way but it doesn't work. It still give me the "No view rendering, null ModelAndView returned. Exiting from "FORWARD" dispatch, status 404, headers={}." error. Did you test it yourself?

Comment: Yes I have an application that works like this. I did not try your example. Did you try to change @RestController to @Controller?

Comment: Yes, this is what I got after I changed to Controller. For RestController, your example will display the "hello-world" string instead.

Comment: that looks like the thymleaf jars are missing. I would think prj1 can just be a dependency that does not need to be a spring boot application itself. prj2 might need the spring boot parent or the spring boot maven plugin to create a propper spring boot uber jar. Do you have a github repo with your example in it?